# Radio group in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm having issues with getting the radiogroup field to work in a ng-repeat.

I have a set of form fields that are repeating:

```
  <div ng-repeat="rpt in repeatables.REPEATGRP">
      <input ng-required="false" name="text1" ng-readonly="false" type="text" ng-model="rpt.data.text1" id="text1" value="" />
      <label for="radio1_1" class="radio-inline">
        <input ng-required="true" name="radio1" type="radio" ng-model="rpt.data.radio1" id="radio1_1" value="1" /> Yes
      </label>
      <label for="radio1_2" class="radio-inline">
        <input ng-required="true" name="radio1" type="radio" ng-model="rpt.data.radio1" id="radio1_2" value="0" /> No
      </label><br/><br/>
  </div>
```

The form data is initiated like this, with 2 sets of fields:

```
  $scope.repeatables = {
    REPEATGRP: [
      {data:{text1: "test 1", radio1: 1}},
      {data:{text1: "test 2", radio1: 0}}
    ]
  };
```

But the 2 radio groups are behaving like they are linked to each other. It's hard to describe, but you can see it in action here: http://plnkr.co/edit/y4pCt0IsDTD8BzeA8SWZ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to don't alter the object, just add the $index variable that is part of the ng-repeat to the name of the input.

```
<input ng-required="true" name="radio1-{{$index}}" type="radio" ng-model="rpt.data.radio1" id="radio1_1" value="1" /> Yes
```

Based on your Plunker, here is working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5KeyBrzLqzAIXrPxIoig?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

just add a property name to your repeteables and set it in your radio buttons.

What it's happening is that as all of them have the same name, the browser groups them as if they are just one set of radio buttons :

(I changed also the id, so you don't have the same id repeated).

HTML:

```
      <label for="radio1_1" class="radio-inline">
        <input ng-required="true" name="{{rpt.name}}" type="radio" ng-model="rpt.data.radio1" id="{{rpt.name}}_1" value="1" /> Yes
      </label>
      <label for="radio1_2" class="radio-inline">
        <input ng-required="true" name="{{rpt.name}}" type="radio" ng-model="rpt.data.radio1" id="{{rpt.name}}_2" value="0" /> No
      </label>
```

SCOPE

```
$scope.repeatables = {
    REPEATGRP: [
    {data:{text1: "test 1", radio1: 1,name:'r1'}},
    {data:{text1: "test 2", radio1: 0,name:'r2'}}
    ]
  };
```

Comment: Thanks. What I don't understand is why the textbox, which also have the same name for the multiple repeating instances, don't have an issue. I guess it's just a limitation for radio fields?

Comment: Because there's a specific behaviour for radio buttons (among all the radio buttons with the same name only one can be selected). This behaviour doesn't exist for text boxes. But when you submit this information, you'll have conflicts with the values when you have textboxes with the same name.